# SQL - how to create a user input for a data pull

Tags: sql

I am trying to get some user input options at the top ("%let startdate = xxx" for example).  I ran the code (see below), and received the following errors: "ERROR: Expression using BETWEEN has components that are of different data types.
ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: enddate, startdate."

I am very new to working in SQL, and I have tried tutorials, but I am not finding anything that explains my problems here.  Any help is much appreciated.

MY CODE :

```
%_eg_conditional_dropds(WORK.ActivityReport);


/*Date Range Selections (all DMONYYYY:H:M:S format)*/

%let startdate = 1Jun2017:0:0:0'dt;
%let enddate = 30Jun2017:0:0:0'dt;
%let groupid=(##, ##, ##, ##, ##);  

/*((user would put in the group ID in place of the number signs, and I want the dates to be variable as well))  */



Proc sql;
CREATE TABLE WORK.ActRep AS
    SELECT DISTINCT
          t1.GRGR_ID,
          t1.DATE, 
/*        convert(varchar,t1.DATE,101),*/
          t1.PROD_C, 
          t1.SBSB_C, 
          t1.MEME_C, 
          /* A_P_A */
            (SUM(t1.A_P_A)) FORMAT=DOLLAR23.2 AS A_P_A, 
          /* B_P_A */
            (SUM(t1.B_P_A)) FORMAT=DOLLAR23.2 AS B_P_A, 
          /* C_P_A */
            (SUM(t1.C_P_A)) FORMAT=DOLLAR23.2 AS C_P_A, 
          /* D_P_A */
            (SUM(t1.D_P_A)) FORMAT=DOLLAR23.2 AS D_P_A, 
          /* SUM_of_NCE */
            (SUM(t1.NCE)) FORMAT=DOLLAR23.2 AS NCE
      FROM FACE t1
    WHERE t1.DATE BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
/*  AND t1.GRGR_ID IN groupid    */
      GROUP BY t1.GRGR_ID,
               t1.DATE,
               t1.PROD_C,
               t1.SBSB_C,
               t1.MEME_C;


;run;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and specify the database engine and programming language.

Comment: Ok, I am confused a bit, but I will try - isn't it just SQL?  I am technically using SAS, is that the database engine?

Comment: The variables you declare at the start are causing your issue. The ' tag is used as a string delimiter in SQL and is being wrongly applied, the date format you are using may also cause you problems. Depending on what type of sql you are using you should try: DECLARE @startdate date SET startdate = '20170601' (for MS SQL SERVER)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WJS, you are correct that I used the ' tag incorrecty, with that fix plus reading through this explanation of the %let function: http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/028-2010.pdf

I discovered that I was missing the ampersand in front of my variables when I attempted to use them.

So by fixing my dates and changing the line

```
WHERE t1.DATE BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
```

to

```
WHERE t1.DATE BETWEEN &startdate AND &enddate
```

my code now works.

Thanks!